SQL state: 42601 Error in PostgreSQL when creating a table
Edited:
I was trying to create a table within PostgreSql server but got an error.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 40: \COPY public.fy24pcard 
         ^ 

SQL state: 42601
Character: 812

and the query looks like this:
\COPY public.fy24pcard 
FROM 'C:\Users\Omitted.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

Can someone help me with this?
I tried importing the file using IMPORT but failed.

As answer from @FrankHeikens say \copy is a psql command. So either use psql or the pgAdmin4 GUI for COPY  as shown here Import/Export data.

You really expect to get an answer without providing any useful information? To the question text add as text the following: 1) Definition of what you mean by IMPORT. 2) What failed and what where the error messages?

\COPY is a command for the psql client, not for pgadmin. Remove the \
